# How to send the request from jsp to servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

How to send the parameter from jsp to servlet?

I have an application in which first the servlet sends a data list to jsp. User selects one option from the list and again jsp sends the selected option to servlet. Then servlet should process the request and send the data related to that selected option again to jsp for rendering.

How can I achieve this using java?

I am following MVC.

Comment: using RequestDispatcher I sent list of elements from servlet to jsp.And in browser with that jsp I have selected one option from that list.Now I want to send this selected value to servlet.How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider user selects some option from option_list on jsp page like

```
<select name="option_list">
<option>abc</option>
</select>
```

Then in servlet you write

```
String opt=request.getParameter("option_list");
//Find the data related to option
```

Consider related data is stored in `String data;` .To send data to same jsp use

```
request.setAttribute("data_to_be_displayed",data);
```

And on jsp you can use

```
<% String  data=(String)request.getAttribute("data_to_be_displayed");%>
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you have enlisted the options in form using post method,
try the following in servlet:

String option = request.getParameter('opt');
// here opt is element name of option in jsp

Comment: Sorry I did not get you.Please can you explain in brief.Where this statement should be called in jsp or servlet.Because in some samples this statement is kept in servlet and jsp also.

Comment: and in jsp the form would lock like as follows:

<form name="myform" action="your_servlet_url" method="post">
<!-- form elements such as list options, submit button goes here.... -->
</form>

Comment: the first code to get the user option to string object is placed in servlet. it's an example only, and your implementation may differ, since the object name 'request' should be define before as a parameter in doGet() method of servlet class.
And the later code (something with form tag) should be placed in the jsp inorder to send request message to the servlet.

Comment: @user2362277 Maybe you should edit your answer : your servlet code + your jsp code would make a full working example, and your answer would be fine. Thanks ;-)